# iOS switft Wordpress api can't get json

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, swift

I'm trying to get a json file from a local Wordpress server and view it with SwiftyJson and Alamofire. I am using this code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:8080/wordpress/feed/json").response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
    print(res)
    let outputString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(outputString)
}
```

It works with other json links but not with the link from my local Wordpress server. I am using the "Feed JSON" plugin on the Wordpress server. When I type the address in my internet browser it views my Wordpress site in json format.

Why doesn't it works in my swift project in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your Wordpress server is running on your iOS device, you have a problem with your URL, as it points to `localhost`, which is by definition, the same computer as the one making the request.

Replace `localhost` with the actual host name or IP address of the server. Note that if you are using virtual hosting, it needs to match the name of the virtual host.